# How to create new git branch with jenkins shell

Tags: git, jenkins

I would like to reach the following:

> 1. In some jenkins job, create a new branch from dev-branch
> 2. do some changes on the new created branch new-branch
> 3. push the new created branch to git repo

I did the following steps in Jenkins:

> 1. I have configured my git repo in the section "Source Code Management" and also the branches to build is my dev-branch.
> 2. In Section Post Steps: Execute shell --> Command I have added the following:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
... do some changes
git add .
git commit -a -m "I have added some changes"
git push -u origin new-branch
```

Now when I run this job I get the following in the console output:

```
+ git checkout -b R1.10.0.0_SII
Switched to a new branch 'new-branch'
+ git add .
+ git commit -a -m 'I have added some changes'
[new-branch 0dc7cf8] I have added some changes
+ git push -u origin new-branch
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

How to create a new branch with jenkins, do some changes and push the new created branch correctly?

Comment: You can refer http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/shell-script-to-assist-with-branch-management-for-tasks-in-git it has the information you want for the shell part

Comment: run `git remote -v` to check if origin does exist. If it doesn't, `git remote add origin git_url` or directly `git push -u git_url new_branch`

Answer (score -1):

1. if you are installed Jenkins on the machine then you need to install git first on the local machine and then set the global username, email, and remote origin for git.
2. if Jenkins running on docker then you have to go inside the Jenkins container and then install git and set global username and email and remote origin.

Try again It will work.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to perform git init command to initialize to parent repository. Then try creating branch and add.

Comment: You can add this as a comment also, Or what you can do is to provide a well-written answer with some commands.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see what's expected in a complete answer